# Rails: how do I set ID or Name attribute in text_field_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= text_field_tag :barcode, params[:barcode] %>
```

generates

```
<input id="barcode" name="barcode" type="text"></input>
```

but I need

```
<input type="text" name="barcode" id="autocomplete"></input>
```

But in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) I did not find a way how to change the ID attribute.

I need to use a text_field_tag because it fills the textbox with params if submit fails.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

try this

```
<%= text_field_tag :barcode, params[:barcode], id: 'autocomplete' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this...

```
<%= text_field_tag :barcode, params[:barcode], :id => 'autocomplete' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`<%= text_field_tag "name_text","value_text", :class => "txBox", :size=>15 %>`

HTML:

`<input type="text" size="15" name="name_text" id="name_text" values="" class="txBox">`